# How to Stop posting fake scores in game center/ leadership board

Tags: android, ios, leaderboard

I am developing a mobile game and need to check for the top scores for that game.
And I am implementing Game Center for that.
1>But how to avoid from entering fake scores in the game center?
2>Is there any way to allow entering only genuine score?
3>Is there a way to find if the app is hacked or not so that based on that we can decide?

Since the App will be developed for both Android and IOS , can I follow single server for updating score ? or need to create own?

Thanks and Regards,
Anil

Comment: Are you asking how you can prevent users from hacking a fake score into the leadership board?  See http://www.eprize.com/engage/news/articles/2012/09/17/how-to-make-your-online-contest-cheater-proof/

Comment: Hi Robert, Thanks for the info.But it doesn't say how to stop/handle !

Comment: Yes it does.  Read it again.  Pay particular attention to the "Preventing Attacks" section.  All of the techniques are social engineering, not technical preventions per se.